# Joining a family member from an EU country?

Tags: schengen-visas, france, family, eu-citizens

I am an EU citizen (but not French) and would like my family member to apply for a French visa. We would arrive in France from different places and meet in Paris to spend a day there and then leave the Schengen zone together.

One of the questions on the visa form asks the following (emphasis mine):

> Do you *join* or travel with a family member from an EU country (excluding France), the EEA or the Swiss Confederation?

Answering "yes" would reduce the number of required documents so we'd like to qualify if possible. But the question is: What exactly do they mean by "joining"?

I will be in France on the date of my family member's arrival there. But I am not residing in France. Would that still count as *joining*?

Comment: But what is the citizenship of your family member?

Comment: @Ana: One of the gray ones: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Visa_exemptions :)

Comment: Joining doesn’t just mean joining someone who lives in a country. But specifically what is the relationship between you and the family member?

Answer (score 2):

Free movement also covers short-term travel, so your being in France is sufficient for this trip to constitute "joining" you.  But unless your family relationship falls under the free movement directive, your relative will need a standard Schengen visa with the application requiring the larger set of supporting documents.

If you don't live together, it is more or less limited to dependent parents, dependent children, and spouse or registered domestic partner.